# Show only questions or only answers?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

When I search for something in the app, the search results include listings for questions and answers, separately. When I am looking for questions to answer, I do not want to see the answer listings.

I am aware of the usual method of using `is:q` or `is:a`, but that is fairly obscure, and a lot of users have no idea that is there. What would be more friendly to new users would be to have another menu next to the sorting menu to show only questions or only answers. It could function much like the tag search capabilities on the main site, where it modifies the search term.

Comment: Does the normal trick work? `is:q` and `is:a`

Comment: "but that is fairly obscure" not obscure at all, the app was made as mirror of the main site (on the other hand, voting to reopen is far more complicated).

Comment: @Braiam By obscure I mean not commonly known.

Comment: Is this a [feature-request] now?

Comment: @MikeM Yes. I thought I tagged it that, but I guess not. Sorry about that.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245813/is-it-possible-to-use-search-queries-in-the-ios-app

Answer (score 3):

Some quick testing seems to confirm Laurel's theory that the `is:(q|a)` operators will work in search on the iOS app.

[image: searching for <code>is:a foo</code> shows only answers] [image: while searching for <code>is:q foo</code> shows only questions]

Comment: Do you know if the app lists advanced search operators anywhere? If it doesn't, I would agree that these tricks are "obscure". There should be a list somewhere directly in the app, because some users (especially on "casual" sites, like Cooking SE) may never have used the desktop version.