# How to show questions and answers in search results

Tags: support, search

If searching for a `[tag]`, the results show only questions. The help page gives the options

`is:question`, `is:answer`, `is:article`

but I would like to see both questions and answers. I tried

```
[tag] is:question or is:answer
```

but this shows only answers

> **Search options** answers only not deleted

So how to search for a tag with both questions and answers in the search results?

I mean, if I don’t specify post type at all, articles are also included. I want to exclude articles from search results while showing answers and questions.

Comment: You could just add an empty string to the search `""` (i.e. show all posts that contain an empty string, thus any post). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+%22%22) (searches for `[java] ""`). Not sure if that is the goto way though

Comment: `or` only works for tag searches, not any other search terms. So you can do `[a] or [b]`.

Comment: There’s no way to do this right now, you can as well make a feature-request

Comment: It seems if you put some invalid option after `is:` it just displays both questions and answers. So you could use something like `is:any`

Comment: @nicael Concerning your edit of the question: if the post type is not specified at all, only questions are shown. That's why I'm asking. I wouldn't mind too much about articles included, but basically I want to **search for a tag - search results show matching questions and answers**

Answer (score 4):

As of current, there is no way to search for questions and answers *excluding articles*. However, since the amount of articles are considerably small compared to Q&A, it is possible to search for *all* posts instead:

- Use empty string `""` or `"`

  - `[tag] ""`
  - `[tag] "`
- Fill the search operator with invalid value, thus resulting in being ignored (e.g. `is:all`, `views:a`)

  - `[tag] is:all`
  - `[tag] views:a`

Comment: I believe the actual question is how to exclude articles from search results

Comment: @nicael that's fair, but Articles are really few/non-existent compared to the amount of Q&A that one can just manually ignore them.

Comment: Yeah but still, author clearly mentions 3 post types and would like to search only among 2 post types, though there’re not really many articles right now, it’s still a valid concern

Comment: In [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324005/show-only-questions-or-only-answers) `is:(q|a)` is mentioned (short for `is:(question|answer)` which seems to be working and would exclude the articles, so do exactly what I want. I didn't find it officially documented but maybe you still want to add it to your answer...

Comment: @Corrl no, that doesn't work either. It's considered invalid and still returns Articles. (Also, that answer was posted back when there were no Collectives and Articles)

Comment: @AndrewT. I see, thanks for clarifying. I'll leave this question open then since the currently possible ways always include the articles

Comment: @Corrl actually, that answer explained that `is:q` or `is:a` could be used on the (now-defunct) mobile apps, but not that the literal `is:(q|a)` worked.

Comment: @AndrewT. I saw it, I tried it and it ***seemed to be working***. As commented above an invalid option seems to be setting the options to *not deleted* so showing everything, that's why it seemed to be working